# How to open chapters of Vim user manual in Vim

Tags: vim

I opened the Vim user manual with the `:h user-manual | only` command (to open it in one window) and now I want to enter/open the separate text files. I tried to put my cursor over a section, such as |usr_01.txt| , and press CTRL-j but nothing happened.

```
Overview ~

Getting Started
|usr_01.txt|  About the manuals
|usr_02.txt|  The first steps in Vim
|usr_03.txt|  Moving around
|usr_04.txt|  Making small changes
|usr_05.txt|  Set your settings
|usr_06.txt|  Using syntax highlighting 
|usr_07.txt|  Editing more than one file
|usr_08.txt|  Splitting windows
```

Comment: This is a question for the [vi stackexchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To navigate to the section under the cursor, you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> (that's a right bracket, not a <kbd>j</kbd>):

> JUMPING AROUND
>
> The text contains hyperlinks between the two parts, allowing you to quickly
> jump between the description of an editing task and a precise explanation of
> the commands and options used for it.  Use these two commands:
>
> ```
> Press  CTRL-]  to jump to a subject under the cursor.
> Press  CTRL-O  to jump back (repeat to go further back).
> ```

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/vimum.html

Answer (score 6):

`:h usr_01.txt` and so on should do it for you.

Comment: This really helped! Now after vimtutor end I can check internal help info!